# Is an answer to an off-topic question automatically low-quality?

Tags: support, review-audits, disputed-review-audits

I just failed a review audit because I marked [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23690143/96982) as OK. I did think about it for a bit before marking it as such, but it seemed to me like a valid answer to the question (and not link-only), albeit that the question itself was off-topic.

The question was

> I'm looking for an open source tool using which one can automate the mobile device applications like contacts, phone...etc. Can anyone please suggest based on their experiences? I know this can be done using Sikuli, but looking for a solution which can be tested on a device.
>
> PS-The device cannot be rooted.

and the answer was

> Have you ever tried Appium? http://appium.io/ It is based on Selenium framework, so the learning curve is faster and you can test both android and iOS applications.

There are a number of other answers that seem equally invalid to me but haven't been deleted. [Update: the question and all answers have now been deleted]

What's the rule here, specifically in relation to an answer that provides a product recommendation and some plausible sounding justification for the recommendation?

Comment: No, because 'off-topic' is opinion-based case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't see that answer but there was a similar (but opposite) meta post the other day. Audit failed after an answer with a few words and a link was supposed to be passed with "looks good". It was argued that the few words constituted an answer on their own, but it was certainly a grey area - and definitely not a good audit candidate.

Bottom line IMO, some audits just aren't great for auditing, but fortunately you'd have to be very unlucky to hit several unfair audits in a row, so when bans kick in (the only negative effect of failing audits) you probably genuinely do need a break from reviewing.

I think these bad audit posts generally come down to this:

Failed an unfair audit, but not banned - don't worry about it, a few bad results here and there do no harm. I've failed many audits but I doubt I've ever been close to a ban.

Failed an unfair audit, now banned - you may have been hard done by this time, but you need to review more carefully.

What I would add is that, when I review a post that clearly is answering an off-topic question, I head straight over to give it a close vote - but that doesn't really help with the audit.

Comment: Makes sense - I've had a few failures I considered unfair before where I could see it probably was just an unfortunate and hard to avoid consequence of the audit system.In this particular case a moderator had actually deleted the answer (it seems for a spam flag) so in a sense the audit was correct to fail me in that I chose something different to an explicit moderator choice.

But I still don't really understand the rationale behind the moderator's approach so I don't know how to be more careful next time.

Answer (score 4):

Not necessarily.

But product recommendation questions do tend to attract these kinds of low-quality answers, and this one is indeed link only (what value does the answer provide, if you don't click on the link?)

Because the scope of Stack Exchange sites can and does change over time, relying on old posts to evaluate topicality seldom works out well.  You're better off referring to resources like [Are answers that just contain links elsewhere really "good answers"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers).

Note that the post you linked attracted a spam flag, which isn't all that surprising.

Comment: "relying on old posts to evaluate topicality seldom works out well." - isn't that exactly what the audit system does? Or only recent questions/answers are used in it now?

Comment: But this post didn't just contain a link elsewhere, it described the contents, which was a perfectly reasonable answer to the stated question.

Comment: Also, what makes it spam?

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam I am guessing that it got marked as spam because the post reads like an advertisement for the link.

Comment: I can sort of see that, but the description of the spam flag is "This answer is effectively an advertisement with no disclosure. It is not useful or relevant, but promotional.", and the answer was definitely relevant to the question and provided useful background as to why it might be a good choice. Anyway, I guess the upshot of this is that I'll just click "Skip" more often if I think someone else might have disliked an answer even if I think it's fine.

Comment: @GaneshSittampalam: The problem, of course, is that the question itself was an off-topic shopping question, which tends to attract these kinds of "try our product" answers.